# Image inpainting offline tool for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

Image inpainting seems to be everywhere: [Vercel](https://inpainter.vercel.app/) (online) or [Cleanup Pictures](https://cleanup.pictures/) (online).

But they all don't fit my needs, which are:

- works offline
- works on Windows (10/11)
- is gratis, also for commercial use, granted by a real license
- should work on images up to at least 2048px
- inpaint works for ~10% of missing pixels

Optional:

- with a prompt on what to insert in the inpaint area, but at the moment I just want to remove unwanted items

Comment: Absolutely with you on this one! Having done some minimal work in pytorch I totally understand why people want to keep their code server-side (it is very hardware-dependent) but it is frustrating that there aren't more tools out there for offline usage. Stable diffusion is the closest but you're going to need some python experience, and honestly it is NOWHERE near as good as photoshop - adobe is currently light-years ahead of the open source community. I hope that changes soon!